# Bootstrap - Classe .table-striped não funciona corretamente dentro de um while

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Estou usando o Bootstrap para fazer um sistema. Na hora de listar as linhas do meu select usando while as linhas não sem zebradas corretamente, saem todas escuras, como se todas as linhas fossem a primeira da tabela (acho que é isso que o Bootstrap está entendendo), porém a exclusão e a edição de cada linha está funcionando perfeitamente, é apenas visual. Segue o trecho do código:

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM USUARIOS ");
                            echo
                            "<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
                          <thead>
                                </tr>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>E-mail</th>
                              <th></th>
                                <tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>";
                          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                                echo
                                "</tr>
                                <td>".$row['nome']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                              <td>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' title='Detalhes' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAlteracaoUsuario' data-whatever-nome='".$row['nome']."' data-whatever-email='".$row['email']."'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' title='Trocar Senha' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAlteracaoSenha' data-whatever-nome='".$row['nome']."' data-whatever-email='".$row['email']."'><i class='fa fa-key'></i></button>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAlteracaoUsuario' data-whatever-id='".$row['id']."' data-whatever-nome='".$row['nome']."' data-whatever-email='".$row['email']."'>Editar</button>
                                <a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Excluir</a>
                              </td>
                                <tr>";
                                }
                            echo
                            "</tbody>
                        </table>";
```

O que posso fazer para concertar isso?
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Cara você teria ai o código final que ele gera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está confundindo abertura de tag com fechamento.
Para abrir uma tag usa-se `<tag>` e para fechar `</tag>`.

No seu código você estava fechando uma tag e depois abrindo, como no trecho:

```
</tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th></th>
<tr>
```

Ficou assim: (ocultei o código dos botões para não ficar muito feio)

```
<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $c =1;
            $row = array('nome' => 'nome', 'email' => 'email', 'id' => 0);

            echo "<tr>\n";

            while($c < 5)
            {
                echo "\t\t\t<td>".$row['nome']."</td>\n\t";
                echo "\t\t<td>".$row['email']."</td>\n\t";
                echo "\t\t<td><a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Excluir</a></td>\n\t";
                echo "\t</tr>\n\n\t\t<tr>\n";
                $c ++;
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Dica, muito `echo` em *html* puro fica feio, mescle HTML com PHP.

Outra coisa que notei foi que no while não parecia ter noção nenhum do que estava fazendo a abrir e fechar linhas, então adaptei colocando uma lógica que sempre uso nas minhas aplicações, no código fonte resultante você pode ver que sobre uma linha a mais (`<tr></tr>`) mas não atrapalha em nada.

Para ficar funcional no PC de qualquer membro coloquei um while sem necessidade de banco de dados, apenas para exemplo.

Finalizando, `\n`(quebra de linha) e `\t` (tabulação, famoso TAB) usados no `echo` foram apenas para identar o código fonte no navegador para que você possa ver a estrutura de uma tabela e pode entender melhor.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!
Com o copiar e colar acabei me confundindo com as tags! No meio do código acaba ficando difícil visualizar esse tipo de erro.
Obrigado também pelas dicas!
Sucesso pra você!